# Convolution of non-periodic function with another function

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing, periodic-functions

We're given a signal $X_a(t)=X_b(t)*[4\cdot \text{sinc}(4t)]$, with $X_b(t)$ being a non-periodic function.

We have to find the periodicity of $X_a(t)$, and the period if it's periodic.

Are there any properties for non-periodic functions that can be used to get the required results?

Comment: By sinc(4t), do you mean sin(4t) or sin(4t)/4t?

Comment: The second one, sin(4t)/4t